# WCF on Windows Phone

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8

My desktop application (WPF server) wants to communicate with Windows Phone by WCF. I prefer .net tcp.

I think I need three projects, namely `WPF server`, `WP client`, `Contracts`. Contracts project is Windows Phone Class Library, targeted WP8.0. Contracts project defines two classes, `interface IPhone` and `class PhoneClient: ClientBase<IPhone>, IPhone`. The target of WP client is also 8.0. WPF server has a reference to Contracts.

Visual Studio shows no error in WPF server project. But when I build WPF server, VS says

> could not find System.ServiceModel, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

. The error occurs at wherer I use PhoneClient.

How could I solve the problem? Is WCF supported in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wcf is definitelly supported on windows phone
2. Having contract library is not required. If you create wcf server you can add service reference in windows phone project and visual studio it will automatically generate data-contract classes for you.
3. If you want to share data-contract library between wpf and wp apps, you should choose portable library, not wp nor wpf class library.
4. Contract library must not contain implementation of service contract, which is PhoneClient class in your case. It should contain only service interface and data-contract classes (method inputs and outputs).
5. I dont know how you get the error message, but System.ServiceModel, Version=2.0.5.0 is old one. Make sure you have added reference to latest verion of System.ServiceModel assembly in both, wpf and wp projects. In contract library it is not required

Comment: Portable library is a key point! And I find out WP doesn't have NettcpBinding, and it seemingly only has BasicHttpBinding.

Comment: Besides, Silverlight only supports asynchronous call.